# Scanner's Read Line returning NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, io

This is my first time using StackOverflow. I am trying to read a text file which consists of a single number one the first line.

```
try {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("HighScores.txt"));
    int temp =Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
    s.close();
    return temp;
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, I get an error:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at GameStart.getHighScore(GameStart.java:334)
    at GameStart.init(GameStart.java:82)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I know that HighScores.txt is not empty, so why is this problem occuring? I tried using BufferedReader, and BufferReader.readLine() return null.

Comment: Is your text file empty ?

Comment: Your `HighScores.txt` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should correct your code as follows

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("HighScores.txt"));
int temp=0;
while(s.hasNextLine){
  temp =Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
}
```

Then `s.nextLine()` will not execute if there is no next line. In this case it is seems to be there is not line(empty file) in your input file.

Comment: When I used this code, s.hasNextLine() is false. I checked HighScores.txt, and it was still not empty; it still had a number in it. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

[Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) swallows errors. Check for them using the [ioException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#ioException--) method.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("HighScores.txt"));
if(!s.hasNextLine()) {
  System.out.println(s.ioException());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> I am trying to read a text file which consists of a single number one the first line.

I wonder if your file ends with a line separator?

From the Javadoc:

> Since this method continues to search through the input looking for a line separator, it may buffer all of the input searching for the line to skip if no line separators are present.

So if the file really only has the number, the Scanner might be confused by the absence of a newline character (or similar).

**Edit:**
I might have used the wrong Javadoc excerpt to support this thesis. The Javadoc also says:

> The position is set to the beginning of the next line.

What if there is no next line? Maybe that's exactly what the Scanner is trying to tell you.

Comment: Your conclusion doesn't follow from your premiss. The same Javadoc also says "excluding any line separator at the end", which clearly implies that the final line terminator may be absent.